# how to convert CString to Bytes

Tags: c++, string, byte, cstring

i am actually tryin to convert a csharp code to c... below is the C# code..

```
CString data = "world is beautiful";    
Byte[] quote = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

in the above code... it converts the string into bytes..similarily is ther a way that i can convert it using C..
Can any body tell what wud be the quivalent code in C?
Please help me guys

Comment: .Net doesn't have a `CString` class; you probably mean `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well CString is a C++ class so doing it in C is a little unlikely.

But if you wish to get it as a standard multi-byte encoded string then you can do the following

```
CString data    = "world is beautiful";
CStringA mbStr  = data;
char* bytes     = mbStr.GetString();
```

Comment: tanx for u reply..
but still its reading it as an string but not as bytes..
does it makes sense

Comment: a char array IS an array of bytes.  Just because you look in a debugger and it interprets it as a set of characters is neither here nor there.  You DO have an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In C the char type is defined as one byte in memory. Hence storing your string as a char * would be equivalent to storing a byte array in C#.

Comment: The poster is asking how to encode a Unicode string as UTF-8.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thats a harsh downvote. The original question didnt mention UTF8, it was just used as an example.