# String to byte conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am working on Visual studio C++.

I have these codes:

```
    CString str; 
    BYTE byBuffer[10000] = { 0 };
    str ="Invalid Command. Spaces are not allowed too!!";
    strcpy_s(reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(byBuffer), 10000, T2CA(str ));
```

The problem is byBuffer = "Invalid Command. Spaces are not allowed too!!"; but after the following line, the string changes. 
  LPBYTE lp=byBuffer ;  Although it works fine for small strings like OK, GOOD JOB. etc..

i am debugging the whole code by setting the breakpoints. moreover this function has been called to another function in which ( LPBYTE lpBuffer) recieved this value.

Plz help

Comment: In what manner is it not working.  what kind of output are you getting?

Comment: Can you please make a small compilable version of the code? What is the T2CA macro definition?

Comment: only first three characters and den garbage value like : Inv@@@@@@@@@@@

Comment: @UnknownGosu, [T2CA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.80).aspx) is from Microsoft.

Comment: this is why I always just use char* in the first place

Comment: What is the reason you don't just write `strcpy_s(reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(byBuffer), 10000, "Invalid Command. Spaces are not allowed too!!");`?

Comment: @SamIam; can you please highlight the mistake by writing exact line. 
thanks

Comment: How are you verifying the contents of `byBuffer` at the end? Perhaps the buffer contains the right stuff but you just don't know it.

Comment: Maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650035/how-to-convert-cstring-to-bytes

Comment: i edited my question- plz have a look again- byBuffer contains that exact string but not lp

Comment: Please post the *exact* code you have, it is important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're showing us looks OK, so I'm going out on a limb and making a guess.

I'm guessing that you're trying to return this buffer from a function:

```
LPBYTE lp = byBuffer;
return lp;
```

If that's the case, then the local variable `byBuffer` is getting destroyed at the end of the function and the pointer no longer points to valid memory. You're lucky if you can see anything recognizable in the output at all.